# compare two phone numbers

Tags: phone-number, libphonenumber

I am trying to find if two phone numbers are same or not (Two same phone number may not be in same format , as +11234567890 is same as 1234567890 and 0011234567890)

I tried PhoneNumberUtils.Compare like this:

```
if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare("+11234567890", "34567890"))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Are same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But it returns true for "+11234567890", "34567890" while they are not same.

Is there any better method to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is using  Google's libphonenumber library

```
PhoneNumberUtil pnu = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

MatchType mt = pnu.isNumberMatch("+11234567890", "34567890");
if( mt == MatchType.NSN_MATCH || mt == MatchType.EXACT_MATCH )
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "are Same" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

if we use `MatchType.SHORT_NSN_MATCH` it will return same result as `PhoneNumberUtils.compare`

Comment: ...which can be found at [Google Internationalization on GitHub](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers).

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation:

> Compare phone numbers a and b, and return true **if they're identical**
>   **enough for caller ID purposes.**

The number is the same because the only difference is the prefix, which is not necessary for compare purposes.

Answer (score 0):

And if you really want to distinguish between a phone number and a phone number plus its a prefix you should string compare method.

```
String number1 = "+11234567890"; 
String number2 = "34567890"; 
number1.compareTo(number2);
```