# How to compare two phone numbers irrespective of format

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, compare

I have similar requirements to those mentioned in this question: [compare two phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200400/compare-two-phone-numbers)

I want to compare phone numbers which are in different formats. For example, +467856753421 = 07856753421 = 7856753421.

Is it possible to do it without using the google library recommended in the linked question?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid using the library recommended on the other question? Also, you've tagged this as regex - is there a reason that you want a regex solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to write a method that sanitises the input string to a standard format, and compare them, but phone numbers have so many different formats that something is bound to slip through the gaps, this is an area where I would strongly recommend a well-tested library that someone else has spent all that time writing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`(^[+]\d{2}|^0*|^00\d\d)(\d*)`

The first capture group is your prefix. The second is your number.
(This might need some adjustment if you have US prefixes which are +1 and 001.)